# C# Code is skipping button2_click and going directly to the Directory.EnumerateFiles

Tags: c#

I am writing an app to find files in a specific directory. Button1 opens FolderBrowserDialog to get path. Button2 actually starts to find the files, but in this case after you press Ok/Open in the selected BrowserDialog it goes straight to Directory.EnumerateFiles skipping the Button2 click. What am I missing? Appreciate the help in advance!

```
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dialog.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal;
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                textBox3.Text = dialog.SelectedPath;
            {
                button2_Click(sender, e);
                {
                  var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dialog.SelectedPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

Comment: Could you fix brackets in your question first? After your `if` statement the code isn't clear.

Comment: Calling `button2_Click()` doesn't _wait_ for the click. It acts as though that buttons was clicked. You need to put the code to enumerate the files _in the `button2_Click()` handler method_, and _don't_ call that method from the `button1_Click()` handler method.

Comment: Please post a reproducible code sample. You are missing curly braces.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thank you for the input! I actually tried this but it tells me the dialog.SelectedPath does not exist in the current context.

Comment: But the code you show is terribly truncated. Please show the entire `button1_Click` and `button2_Click` functions

Comment: _"it tells me the dialog.SelectedPath does not exist in the current context."_ -- that's true. You need to save the value elsewhere, e.g. in a non-static field, so that the `button2_Click()` handler method can access it.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Oh okay. Thank you, Unfortunately I'm really new to c#. Do you mind telling me how I can do that?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19672115/use-a-variable-from-another-method-in-c-sharp